# Add JLabel to JPanel in TabbedPane after action performed event in another Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, event-listener

I want to add JLabel to JPanel (say VisualPanel,which is inside a JFrame) based on the action-performed event (JButton) occurred on another JPanel(say JobPanel) (separate class but add to the JFrame).

How to get the VisualPanel object inside the JobPanel to add the JLabel?

I tried importing the JFrame into JPanel and get the VisualPanel instance but somehow i am getting into infinite recursion.

My question is my design approach correct?. If not how should i go about it? 
if my design is correct any suggestion in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give `VisualPanel` a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) with two panels: one panel that has the `JLabel` and one that doesn't. Give your `JButton` an `ActionListner` that will `show()` the card you want. Then you can use `setSelectedIndex()` to select the `VisualPanel` tab. See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for examples.